# How to avoid widows-orphans with mdframed?

Tags: page-breaking, mdframed, widows-orphans

I have a document with a lot of mdframed boxes ; which option can I set to avoid 'widow' lines at the end of the box (that is, avoid to have small parts of boxes on new pages)?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Your abstract.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{mdframed}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue. Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem lacinia consectetur. Donec ut libero sed arcu vehicula ultricies a non tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ut gravida lorem. Ut turpis felis, pulvinar a semper sed, adipiscing id dolor. Pellentesque auctor nisi id magna consequat sagittis. Curabitur dapibus enim sit amet elit pharetra tincidunt feugiat nisl imperdiet. Ut convallis libero in urna ultrices accumsan. Donec sed odio eros. Donec viverra mi quis quam pulvinar at malesuada arcu rhoncus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In rutrum accumsan ultricies. Mauris vitae nisi at sem facilisis semper ac in est.
\end{mdframed}

\begin{mdframed}
Vivamus fermentum semper porta. Nunc diam velit, adipiscing ut tristique vitae, sagittis vel odio. Maecenas convallis ullamcorper ultricies. Curabitur ornare, ligula semper consectetur sagittis, nisi diam iaculis velit, id fringilla sem nunc vel mi. Nam dictum, odio nec pretium volutpat, arcu ante placerat erat, non tristique elit urna et turpis. Quisque mi metus, ornare sit amet fermentum et, tincidunt et orci. Fusce eget orci a orci congue vestibulum. Ut dolor diam, elementum et vestibulum eu, porttitor vel elit. Curabitur venenatis pulvinar tellus gravida ornare. Sed et erat faucibus nunc euismod ultricies ut id justo. Nullam cursus suscipit nisi, et ultrices justo sodales nec. Fusce venenatis facilisis lectus ac semper. Aliquam at massa ipsum. Quisque bibendum purus convallis nulla ultrices ultricies. Nullam aliquam, mi eu aliquam tincidunt, purus velit laoreet tortor, viverra pretium nisi quam vitae mi. Fusce vel volutpat elit. Nam sagittis nisi dui.
\end{mdframed}

\begin{mdframed}
Vivamus fermentum semper porta. Nunc diam velit, adipiscing ut tristique vitae, sagittis vel odio. Maecenas convallis ullamcorper ultricies. Curabitur ornare, ligula semper consectetur sagittis, nisi diam iaculis velit, id fringilla sem nunc vel mi. Nam dictum, odio nec pretium volutpat, arcu ante placerat erat, non tristique elit urna et turpis. Quisque mi metus, ornare sit amet fermentum et, tincidunt et orci.

Widow lines.
\end{mdframed}

%\begin{mdframed}...\end{mdframed}\begin{mdframed}...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. It would help if you could show us a minimal working example so we can see what you've got. This will show you've done some research and will help others because they won't have to start from scratch.

Comment: I added a PDF screenshot. Code is just \mdframed{..} with no options.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot but if you want others to help you you _must_ provide code. It has happened too many times that people tried to help but that they used different input than the person asking the question, which means they had wasted their time because the person asking the question was too lazy to provide the minimum working example (or didn't care). If you need answer, you will really increase your chances if you provide some code. Note that this should be a full LaTeX input document that somebody can copy-and-paste and compile.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem.  In your example, you have three framed boxes.  Only the last has what you call an orphan (widow actually), but in reality it is not a widow, because you began a new 2-word paragraph, whereas a widow is the remnants of an existing paragraph.  So it is not clear what you would prefer the output to look like.

Comment: you can avoid having the last, two-word, paragraph broken to a new page by inserting `\par\nobreak` at the end of the previous paragraph (no blank line before it, please), but that comes at the cost of cutting the page before the last line of the penultimate paragraph -- a *real* widow.

Comment: Just add `\nopagebreak` before the one line paragraph. However, cases like this one should be dealt with at the very last stage of document production. You have to make a conscious decision whether to allow a pseudowidow or a real widow or neither.

Comment: To avoid true widows (a page break just before the last line of a paragraph) set `\widowpenalty=10000`. Do it locally inside the problem `mdframed` environment, or globally in the preamble. Personally, I find even two lines alone at the top of a page look bad when framed, and would reword the paragraph if it happened (or, preferably, never use framed text).